# How do I compress and encrypt a string to another string?

Tags: c#, .net, string, encryption, compression

The program that I am working on saves the snapshot of the current state to a xml file. I would like to store this in database (as blob) instead of xml.

Firstly, I think xml files are quite space-consuming and redundant, so we would like to compress the string in some way before storing in in the database. In addition, we would also like to introduce a simple cryptography so that people won't be able to figure out what it means without at least a simple key/password.

Note that I want to store it in the database as blob, so zipping it and then encrypting the zip file won't do, I guess.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Really, searching for "compress c#" and "encrypt c#" won't get you what you need?

Comment: See [How to: Encrypt a Column of Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179331.aspx) to see if that fits the bill.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089150/net-compression-of-xml-to-store-in-sql-server-database?

Comment: @ripper234 mostly I got file compression and encryption, which is hard to store in a database

Comment: Just compress the file and save the stream as a memory stream into a byte array and safe that as a blob.

Comment: Yeah, there is no need to stream it to a file, there should be plenty compression and encryption techniques available in .net that keep the data in memory. If you want memory performance, you should try and find streams for everything so you can stream directly into the database without creating byte array buffers.

Comment: @JeffSiver - it seems to be a duplicate, but that question is only partially answered and not accepted by the person asking it (and the answers seem a bit lacking in detail at the time of writing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compress the XML data with [DeflateStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx) and write it's output to a MemoryStream. Then call `.ToArray()` method to obtain your blob data. You can also do encryption with .NET in a similar way as well (after compression of course). If you believe deflate is not enough to save space, then try this library: [XWRT](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xwrt/).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, have a look at your serialization mechanism. The whole point of XML is that it's human readable. If that's no longer an important goal for you then it might be time to look at other serialization technologies which would be more suited to database storage (compressing XML into binary completely defeats the point of it :)

As an alternative format, [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/) could be a good choice.

Comment: I strongly disagree with your analysis. You can still read the XML when you are testing the business logic of your application. You can still intercept the XML after decryption and decompressing as well. One of the arguments *in favor of* XML is that it *can* be compressed, so that the human readable data does not take up too much space during transit or storage.

Comment: @owlstead That is a fair point, but the OP did not mention that the data ever needed to be read by a human - and XML, even when compressed, is always bigger than binary data :) However the real point is that it's important to carefully consider which storage format is best for your needs in any given scenario - a lot of people seem to default to XML when there may be better alternatives in some cases.

Comment: on the other hand, the OP already got XML and would have to rewrite the serialization if he had to switch. The OP has concluded that zipping and encryption would not fit his model because he wants to have a blob, but that's a very strange conclusion, which the OP reached without arguments.