# How to store hashed password in database

Tags: c#, sql, hash, passwords, sha1

I am trying to store hashed password in sql express database. but I am not able to do that one.
Here is my code:

```
SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();

byte[] encode = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pass));

string cmd = "insert into tblLogin (username,password,email,state,active) values ('"+name+"',"+encode+",'"+email+"','"+state +"',"+ active + ")" ;
```

And in database I kept password as varbinary.

Here my problem is I am getting value of encode as System.Byte[] but not hashed value.
How can I do this, I tried to find and I am getting how to hash password but not how to store password.

Here my main problem is How can I construct Insert query and store Byte[] into database?

Comment: Read this, you need cast the value... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067470/sql-query-to-store-text-data-in-a-varbinarymax

Comment: Passwords should really be salted as well.  In fact, why not just use the `System.Web.Helpers.Crypto.HashPassword(password)` which will automatically salt the password and make it cryptographically strong?

Comment: @MystereMan : I am happy to do that, but afterwards how can I compare it with user input's password or retrieve password in case of Password recovery? I tried to do this but I am not able to locate ...Helpers namespace.

Comment: @user1782698 - You can't recover hashed passwords.  They're one way.  That's the point of hashing.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.crypto(v=vs.111).aspx (if you notice there is also a VerifyHashedPassword function)

Comment: Yes. This is why proper site never have passsword recovery like this - they can generate a new password for you, but never recover the old one.

Comment: Instead of using a fast hashing algorithm, you better use a slow key derivation function like PBKDF2 or BCrypt to hash passwords. CSharp has built-in support for [PBKDF2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var provider = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider(salt);
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
string result = Convert.ToBase64String(provider.ComputeHash(bytes)); // store it
```

Answer (score 3):

Save it as a varchar, not varbinary.

Comment: Till now I am not bothering about Datatype, but I am bothering about 'encode' variable which is giving me value System.Byte[]  instead of hashed output.

Comment: @Pranav - `nvarchar` is multi-byte.  SHA1 is single-byte.

Comment: @TheSmose - I tried your manner but it store in database as  2 abc System.Byte[] a@b.com ACT True. Is it expected output??